# HTML attribute bug in featherlight

Tags: jquery, featherlight.js

I've been trying to incorporate featherlight in my project and so far found it quite easy to work with. I have a requirement where I am loading an image gallery/slider inside featherlight. That is, when the user clicks a link, it opens featherlight and the image slideshow as an iFrame. I'm not sure if there is any better way to do it, but in doing so, I think I have run into a bug. It seems like featherlight does not recognize any iframe parameters passed in the HTML tag by using data-featherlight-xxx convention. For example,

If I want to set the size of the iFrame using something like:

```
<a class="book-icon" href="image-slideshow.html"  data-featherlight="iframe" data-featherlight-iframeWidth="992px" data-featherlight-iframeHeight="556px" data-featherlight-scrolling="false"/>
```

The code has no effect on the actual iFrame. Upon going through the code it turns out the culprit is the following line (line 61):

```
regex = new RegExp('^' + prefix + '([A-Z])(.*)');
```

Here the assumption is that the attributes will be camel case and prefixed with iframe as in the example above. However, it turns out that all attributes are being converted to lower case somewhere in the code and the above pattern match fails. If I convert the above to [A-Z] to [a-z] it works as expected.

Also, is there a better way to do it? That is, instead of loading up lightbox first and then slideshow, perhaps use another library that combines the two into one?

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `data-featherlight-iframe-height`, not `data-featherlight-iframeHeight`, etc...